# Using rspec Ruby test to call an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How would I go about implementing an `rspec` test that is supposed to throw an error? Below I have a class with the following field definitions

```
attr_accessor :name
attr_accessor :title
attr_writer :salary
```

And below is the test. It basically you should be able to input new values for `:name` and `:title`, but `:salary` should only be instantiated one time and one time only (in the constructor).

```
it 'does not respong to :salary=' do
  (subject.salary=100).should raise_error
end
```

Here is my first attempt at making this test pass, however I still receive an error

```
def :salary=(input)
  nil
end
```

Error message:

```
def :salary=(input)
     ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RSpec syntax (recent version at least) for making an assertion on an error should be something like:

```
it 'does not respond to :salary=' do
  expect { subject.salary = 100 }.to raise_error
end
```

You're also getting a syntax error (not the desired one). Omit the colon.

```
def salary=(value)
end
```